# Parameter to make the ckeditor not editable?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

is there a parameter to make the ckeditor not editable?
this is my code to see the component. i'm in angular

```
<ckeditor 
  [(ngModel)]="salesCondition.DeliveryTimeHtmlFormatted" 
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
</ckeditor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a `[readonly]="true"` parameter you can use to disable editing of editor.

Use it like :

```
<ckeditor 
  [(ngModel)]="salesCondition.DeliveryTimeHtmlFormatted" 
  [readonly]="true"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
</ckeditor>
```

Comment: Thanks, work :)

Do you also know a parameter to remove the keys at the top of the ckeditor?

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark resolved. You can find more options here. https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-removeButtons